# Read perf counters of a specific userspace process from the kernel

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, performancecounter, perf

I'm using `perf` to measure tlb misses of a userspace process. Then, when a system call comes, I want to read userspace misses, i have a syscall handler at the kernel and i need to read or extract from kernel module. (I don't want to use strace). I examined the `task_struct` and saw a variable named `perf_event_ctxp`. I wonder if it would be possible for me to read the miss numbers from here, I couldn't find any information in the documentation. or do you have any idea where I can read the counter values specific to a process on the kernel side (started with perf).

Answer (score 0):

First, there is a flag for measuring only in-kernel events. From [perf-record(1)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/perf-record.1.html),

```
 --all-kernel
       Configure all used events to run in kernel space.
```

Next, there are several hardware events on x86 for different kinds of TLB misses. For example, on my machine, the following hardware events are available:

```
# perf list
...
dTLB-load-misses
dTLB-loads
dTLB-store-misses
dTLB-stores
iTLB-load-misses
iTLB-loads
...
```

So, you can use any of these events, and the `--all-kernel` flag. For example, if you want to measure the number of dTLB load and store misses in the kernel for ls(1), the following command should suffice:

```sh
perf record --all-kernel -e dTLB-store-misses -e dTLB-load-misses -- ls
```

Comment: I don't want to read kernel misses, I want to read misses of a userspace process from a kernel module.

Comment: So, you essentially want to do what perf does, but inside a kernel module? Why do you want to measure something that can be done in userspace in kernel space instead?

Comment: no, i'm going to use perf anyway. If there is a variable in perf where these miss numbers are kept, I want to reach it with pid from a kernel module, i just posted the `task_struct` for that purpose.

Comment: @qqq: It won't be a variable where "miss numbers" are kept, it will be a "counter #1" or something for whatever event the first programmable counter is counting.  (And some other part of the data structure recording what event-number that is.  The mapping of that number to a name like `dTLB-store-misses` is probably only in the `perf` tool itself.)  For a one-off quick&dirty hack, you might just hard-code which part of the perf context to look at after figuring it out, and invoke `perf` in a consistent way.